# Change colors for theme aware applications for Windows Phone 7

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I'm wanting to change the color of a rectangle depending on what theme the user has chosen on their phone.

**EG.**
When the user has their device's theme color set to light a rectangle should be blue and when the theme is set to dark it should be a grey.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a custom resource dictionary implementation which selects another dictionary at runtime without a performance penalty and works in the Visual Studio designer. You would use it like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <custom:ThemeResourceDictionary>
    <custom:ThemeResourceDictionary.LightResources>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/ThemeManagement;component/Resources/Light.xaml" />
    </custom:ThemeResourceDictionary.LightResources>
    <custom:ThemeResourceDictionary.DarkResources>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/ThemeManagement;component/Resources/Dark.xaml" />
    </custom:ThemeResourceDictionary.DarkResources>
  </custom:ThemeResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Where `Light.xaml` and `Dark.xaml` would contain resources with the same names.

You can get the code and read more about it [on my blog](http://blog.richardszalay.com/2011/06/11/practical-support-for-light-dark-themes-on-windows-phone-7/).

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a detailed response. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of thing would be able to determine what the theme is set to (dark or light).  You might want to build it into a property that you can bind to for your brush.

```
Visibility v = (Visibility)Resources["PhoneLightThemeVisibility"];
if (v == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
{
    // set your brush to blue
}
else
{
    // set your brush to grey
}
```

You can also get the user's selected accent colour with the `PhoneAccentBrush` if you need to take that into account as well.

Comment: There is also the PhoneDarkThemeOpacity to access as an alternative, returning 1 or 0 - you may find a complete list of all internal WP7-Theme-Resources as a cheat-sheet here: http://bit.ly/kzhoog :)