# How to create a brush that supports both dark and light themes?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, themes

I'm working with WP7, and i'd like to create a custom brush (as a local resource) that uses different colors for dark and light themes (for instace, red if the theme is black and blue if it's white).

How do i do it?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change colors for theme aware applications for Windows Phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651312/change-colors-for-theme-aware-applications-for-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integrated/system brushes do not change their properties based on the theme, a *different set of brushes* is included based on the current theme. You can see the various versions of this in `%programfiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Design`

I wrote a [custom `ResourceDictionary`](http://blog.richardszalay.com/2011/06/11/practical-support-for-light-dark-themes-on-windows-phone-7/) that implements theme support in the exact same way: by loading the appropriate theme dictionary depending on the light/dark theme.

Here is a sample that uses it. It works in the Visual Studio designer as well as Blend, but doesn't support white theme preview in Blend because Blend loads resources in a way that cannot be reproduced.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <custom:ThemeResourceDictionary>
        <custom:ThemeResourceDictionary.LightResources>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ThemeManagement;component/Resources/Light.xaml" />
        </custom:ThemeResourceDictionary.LightResources>
        <custom:ThemeResourceDictionary.DarkResources>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ThemeManagement;component/Resources/Dark.xaml" />
        </custom:ThemeResourceDictionary.DarkResources>
    </custom:ThemeResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The above code loads in the resources from two different files, but they could just as easily be declared inline like any other ResourceDictionary.

The source for `ThemeResourceDictionary` is available on my original blog post, but it's also on [a different Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131982/how-to-setup-button-background-image-either-theme-is-dark-or-white) in case my blog ever implodes.

Comment: Very interesting, i like your solution but it's still not good enough for my UX designer, because what she can't see in Blend doesn't exist ;)

Comment: It will appear in Blend, it just won't change to white when she uses the theme preview feature. IMO, you're not going to get any closer than this - I went through half of the Blend source in Reflector trying to find a way to do it properly.

Comment: The idea is great but it doesn't seem to work or I'm doing something wrong. It works in runtime but the designer cannot find any keys from dark and light files.

Comment: @alex.49.98 It's possible you're not doing anything wrong. This solution was based on Winodws Phone 7.1, so I'm not sure it translates to the latest WP8.1 application model.

Comment: There is at least one difference from your example which I didn't notice in the beginning. I have all that in a UserControl.Resources not in the Application.Resources but fortunately I found a solution anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to manage brushes you apply to your elements yourself from code. Currently, I have found this to be the only way of adjusting to a different PhoneBackgroundColor.

For example:

In xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="Some text" Foreground="{Binding VariableTextColor}"/>
```

In code

```
var backgroundColor = (System.Windows.Media.Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundColor"];

if(backgroundColor == "#FF000000") //Dark theme selected
VariableTextColor = RedBrush;
else
VariableTextColor = WhiteBrush;
```

Another aproach using [PhoneDarkThemeVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) resource:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if the application is running in the dark theme
    /// </summary>
    private bool IsDarkTheme
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsDesignMode)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return (Visibility)Application.Current
                    .Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"] == Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the [PhoneDarkThemeVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552(v=vs.92).aspx) instead of compraing the BackgroundColor. Your code isn't compatible with a vendor-specific background colour! Also I think having two resource-dictionaries with different styles in, is a better approach than using random C# for this!

Comment: Good point. Thank you. I was unaware that there are vendor-specific background colors. My HTC has only dark and light.

Comment: The new HTC Titan have a white background for the Dark Theme. (Don't ask me why.)

Comment: I don't like this solution, i want to create a custom brush that the UX designer could use freely, without any code changes. This should work exactly like any of the other integrated brushes that change their color without any code on my app.

Comment: Claus why not? is it because of the Metro style enforcement?

Answer (score 0):

The approach described by Richard Szalay didn't work in my case either because I needed it in a UserControl or because of something else, however it is really close to the answer. My project is Silverlight Windows Phone 8.1 project and I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with the latest updates. Probably that was the problem. This is what helped in my case

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="/Application;component/Controls/NumberKeyboard.Dark.xaml" />
            <windows:ThemeSelector>
               <windows:ThemeSelector.Dark>
                  <ResourceDictionary Source="/Application;component/Controls/NumberKeyboard.Dark.xaml" />
               </windows:ThemeSelector.Dark>
               <windows:ThemeSelector.Light>
                  <ResourceDictionary Source="/Application;component/Controls/NumberKeyboard.Light.xaml" />
               </windows:ThemeSelector.Light>
            </windows:ThemeSelector>
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

         <Style x:Key="KeyboardButton" TargetType="controls:SimpleButton">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="45" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
         </Style>
         <Style x:Key="NumberButton" TargetType="controls:SimpleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource KeyboardButton}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBrush}" />
         </Style>
         <Style x:Key="ControlButton" TargetType="controls:SimpleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource KeyboardButton}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBrush}" />
         </Style>
         <Style x:Key="ActionButton" TargetType="controls:SimpleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource KeyboardButton}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
         </Style>
      </ResourceDictionary>
   </UserControl.Resources>
```

The key line is `<ResourceDictionary Source="/Application;component/Controls/NumberKeyboard.Dark.xaml" />` right before `<windows:ThemeSelector>`. That line is necessary for the VS designer to display everything right and ThemeSelector overrides the styles in runtime accordingly to the current theme dark or light.